# Able to compile native code from apdfviewer?

Tags: android, pdf

I wonder if anyone else had problems running the ./ndk-build on [apdfviewer](http://code.google.com/p/apdfviewer/)?

I've everything working and set.. but i get errors for missing files (SkCanvas.h, SkPaint.h) .. and others related to 'LOGE'..? (i get those on cygwin console)

Can't figure out what am I missing... well, besides those missing files... but i "don't buy" that the developer has forgotten... I think I'm missing some import...

Please help...

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

`SkCanvas.h` is part of [skia, 2D Graphics Library](http://code.google.com/p/skia/). it's one of the build dependences.